# How work this obfuscation, and how deobfuscate?

Tags: javascript

```
Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§=~[];Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§={___:++Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§,$$$$:(![]+"")[Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§],__$:++Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§,$_$_:(![]+"")[Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§],_$_:++Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§,$_$$:({}+"")[Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§],$$_$:(Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§[Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§]+"")[Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§],_$$:++Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§,$$$_:(!""+"")[Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§],$__:++Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§,$_$:++Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§,$$__:({}+"")[Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§],$$_:++Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§,$$$:++Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§,$___:++Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§,$__$:++Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§};Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_=(Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_=Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§+"")[Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_$]+(Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$=Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_[Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$])+(Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$=(Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$+"")[Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$])+((!Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§)+"")[Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$$]+(Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__=Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_[Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_])+(Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$=(!""+"")[Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$])+(Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._=(!""+"")[Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$_])+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_[Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_$]+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$;Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$=Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$+(!""+"")[Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$$]+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$;Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$=(Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.___)[Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_][Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_];Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$(Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$(Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$+"\""+"$('<\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$__+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$_+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.___+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$__+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.___+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$$+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$__+"=\\\""+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_$_+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$$+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$$+"/\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$_+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$$+"/\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$__+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$$+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.___+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._+"/\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.___+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_$_+"/\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_$_+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$_+"."+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$__+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$$_+".\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$_+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$$+"?\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+"="+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+"\\\"><\\\\/\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$__+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$_+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.___+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__+">')."+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_$_+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.___+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.___+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$$_+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_$+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$__+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$+"(\\\""+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_$$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_$+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+"\\\"),\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$_+"$('<\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$__+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$_+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.___+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$__+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.___+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$$+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$__+"=\\\""+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_$_+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$$+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$$+"/\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$_+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$$+"/\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$__+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$$+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.___+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._+"/\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.___+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_$_+"/\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_$_+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$_+".\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_$_+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+"_"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__+".\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$_+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$$+"?\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+"="+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+"\\\"><\\\\/\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$__+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$_+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.___+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__+">')."+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_$_+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.___+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.___+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$$_+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_$+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$_+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$__+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$+"(\\\""+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$_$$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§._$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$_$+"\\"+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.$$$+Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§.__$+"\\\");"+"\"")())();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This obfuscated code is taking advantage of the wide possibilities to name Javascript variables. This makes a simple-obfuscated Javascript code to look much more scarier.

As noted in the great article [Valid JavaScript variable names](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers) and taken by me from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9337047/7193722), Javascript variables can be represented using a wide-range of characters:

> An identifier must start with `$`, `_`, or any character in the Unicode
>   categories “[Uppercase letter (Lu)](http://graphemica.com/categories/uppercase-letter)”, “[Lowercase letter (Ll)](http://graphemica.com/categories/lowercase-letter)”,
>   “[Titlecase letter (Lt)](http://graphemica.com/categories/titlecase-letter)”, “[Modifier letter (Lm)](http://graphemica.com/categories/modifier-letter)”, “[Other letter (Lo)](http://graphemica.com/categories/other-letter)”,
>   or “[Letter number (Nl)](http://graphemica.com/categories/letter-number)”.
>
> The rest of the string can contain the same characters, plus any
>   U+200C *zero width non-joiner characters*, U+200D *zero width joiner*
>   *characters*, and characters in the Unicode categories “[Non-spacing mark
>   (Mn)](http://graphemica.com/categories/nonspacing-mark)”, “[Spacing combining mark (Mc)](http://graphemica.com/categories/spacing-combining-mark)”, “[Decimal digit number (Nd)](http://graphemica.com/categories/decimal-digit-number)”, or
>   “[Connector punctuation (Pc)](http://graphemica.com/categories/connector-punctuation)”.

To begin deobfuscate the code I recommend to first rename the variable name into more readable one, let's say `x`. Using your favorite editor, replace every instance of `Ø Ø¡Ø¢Ø£Ø¤Ø¥Ø¦Ø§` to `x`. Then put a new line after each semicolon to make the reading easier:

```
x=~[];
x={___:++x,$$$$:(![]+"")[x],__$:++x,$_$_:(![]+"")[x],_$_:++x,$_$$:({}+"")[x],$$_$:(x[x]+"")[x],_$$:++x,$$$_:(!""+"")[x],$__:++x,$_$:++x,$$__:({}+"")[x],$$_:++x,$$$:++x,$___:++x,$__$:++x};
x.$_=(x.$_=x+"")[x.$_$]+(x._$=x.$_[x.__$])+(x.$$=(x.$+"")[x.__$])+((!x)+"")[x._$$]+(x.__=x.$_[x.$$_])+(x.$=(!""+"")[x.__$])+(x._=(!""+"")[x._$_])+x.$_[x.$_$]+x.__+x._$+x.$;
x.$$=x.$+(!""+"")[x._$$]+x.__+x._+x.$+x.$$;
x.$=(x.___)[x.$_][x.$_];
x.$(x.$(x.$$+"\""+"$('<\\"+x.__$+x.$$_+x._$$+x.$$__+"\\"+x.__$+x.$$_+x._$_+"\\"+x.__$+x.$_$+x.__$+"\\"+x.__$+x.$$_+x.___+x.__+"\\"+x.$__+x.___+"\\"+x.__$+x.$$_+x._$$+"\\"+x.__$+x.$$_+x._$_+x.$$__+"=\\\""+x.$_$_+"\\"+x.__$+x.$$_+x._$$+"\\"+x.__$+x.$$_+x._$$+x.$$$_+x.__+"\\"+x.__$+x.$$_+x._$$+"/\\"+x.__$+x.$_$+x._$_+"\\"+x.__$+x.$$_+x._$$+"/\\"+x.__$+x.__$+x.$_$+x.$_$_+x.__+"\\"+x.__$+x.$__+x.$$$+"\\"+x.__$+x.$_$+x.___+"\\"+x.__$+x.$$$+x.__$+x._+"/\\"+x.__$+x.___+x._$$+x.$$$_+x.$_$+x.$_$_+"/\\"+x.__$+x.$$_+x.$$$+x.$_$_+"\\"+x.__$+x.$_$+x.__$+"\\"+x.__$+x.$$_+x._$_+"."+x.$$__+x._$+"\\"+x.__$+x.$$_+x._$_+x.$$$_+".\\"+x.__$+x.$_$+x._$_+"\\"+x.__$+x.$$_+x._$$+"?\\"+x.__$+x.$$_+x.$$_+"="+x.__$+x.$$_+"\\\"><\\\\/\\"+x.__$+x.$$_+x._$$+x.$$__+"\\"+x.__$+x.$$_+x._$_+"\\"+x.__$+x.$_$+x.__$+"\\"+x.__$+x.$$_+x.___+x.__+">')."+x.$_$_+"\\"+x.__$+x.$$_+x.___+"\\"+x.__$+x.$$_+x.___+x.$$$_+"\\"+x.__$+x.$_$+x.$$_+x.$$_$+"\\"+x.__$+x._$_+x.$__+x._$+"(\\\""+x.$_$$+x._$+x.$$_$+"\\"+x.__$+x.$$$+x.__$+"\\\"),\\"+x.__$+x._$_+"$('<\\"+x.__$+x.$$_+x._$$+x.$$__+"\\"+x.__$+x.$$_+x._$_+"\\"+x.__$+x.$_$+x.__$+"\\"+x.__$+x.$$_+x.___+x.__+"\\"+x.$__+x.___+"\\"+x.__$+x.$$_+x._$$+"\\"+x.__$+x.$$_+x._$_+x.$$__+"=\\\""+x.$_$_+"\\"+x.__$+x.$$_+x._$$+"\\"+x.__$+x.$$_+x._$$+x.$$$_+x.__+"\\"+x.__$+x.$$_+x._$$+"/\\"+x.__$+x.$_$+x._$_+"\\"+x.__$+x.$$_+x._$$+"/\\"+x.__$+x.__$+x.$_$+x.$_$_+x.__+"\\"+x.__$+x.$__+x.$$$+"\\"+x.__$+x.$_$+x.___+"\\"+x.__$+x.$$$+x.__$+x._+"/\\"+x.__$+x.___+x._$$+x.$$$_+x.$_$+x.$_$_+"/\\"+x.__$+x.$$_+x.$$$+x.$_$_+"\\"+x.__$+x.$_$+x.__$+"\\"+x.__$+x.$$_+x._$_+".\\"+x.__$+x.$_$+x.$_$+x.$_$_+"\\"+x.__$+x.$_$+x.__$+"\\"+x.__$+x.$_$+x.$$_+"_"+x._$+x._+x.__+".\\"+x.__$+x.$_$+x._$_+"\\"+x.__$+x.$$_+x._$$+"?\\"+x.__$+x.$$_+x.$$_+"="+x.$$_+"\\\"><\\\\/\\"+x.__$+x.$$_+x._$$+x.$$__+"\\"+x.__$+x.$$_+x._$_+"\\"+x.__$+x.$_$+x.__$+"\\"+x.__$+x.$$_+x.___+x.__+">')."+x.$_$_+"\\"+x.__$+x.$$_+x.___+"\\"+x.__$+x.$$_+x.___+x.$$$_+"\\"+x.__$+x.$_$+x.$$_+x.$$_$+"\\"+x.__$+x._$_+x.$__+x._$+"(\\\""+x.$_$$+x._$+x.$$_$+"\\"+x.__$+x.$$$+x.__$+"\\\");"+"\"")())();
```

Now, without diving deeper into the code you can see that the code is combined from 6 lines. The first five are variable declarations and applying values to them, whereas the last line is the actual execution of the code (*notice the `()` at the end which is a call for a function*).

The fastest way, in my opinion, to understand what the code does is to simply replace the `()` at the end with `.toString()`. This will make the program print the final code instead of executing it. Thus, with just a simple step you can deobfuscate and understand the code.

**NOTE:** don't execute an obfuscated or possibly-malicious code on your machine. Use virtual machine or another safe environment to execute it.

```
x=~[];
...
...
< truncated for readability >
...
..."\\"+x.__$+x.$$$+x.__$+"\\\");"+"\"")()).toString();
```

You can see that the following code is being printed to your screen:

```
"function anonymous(
) {
$('<script src="assets/js/Matghyu/Ce5a/wair.core.js?v=16"><\/script>').appendTo("body"),
$('<script src="assets/js/Matghyu/Ce5a/wair.main_out.js?v=6"><\/script>').appendTo("body");
}"
```

Now we can understand that the obfuscated code is appending two `<script>` tags to the `body` of the HTML page.

If you want to you can always try to understand how the final code was built but I usually stop here since I already figured out what the program does and following the obfuscation method might cause a headache sometimes.

Comment: "NOTE: don't execute an obfuscated or possibly-malicious code on your machine. Use virtual machine or another safe environment to execute it." So should I turn off JavaScript in my browser, then? Because most JavaScript these days is minified, if only because it starts up faster that way...

Answer (score 5):

It just uses very difficult to read variable names and do some JS trickery to confuse you what it does. If you replace those strange characters you'll get a bit of more readable form

```
a=~[];
a={___:++a,$$$$:(![]+"")[a],__$:++a,$_$_:(![]+"")[a],_$_:++a,$_$$:({}+"")[a],$$_$:(a[a]+"")[a],_$$:++a,$$$_:(!""+"")[a],$__:++a,$_$:++a,$$__:({}+"")[a],$$_:++a,$$$:++a,$___:++a,$__$:++a};
a.$_=(a.$_=a+"")[a.$_$]+(a._$=a.$_[a.__$])+(a.$$=(a.$+"")[a.__$])+((!a)+"")[a._$$]+(a.__=a.$_[a.$$_])+(a.$=(!""+"")[a.__$])+(a._=(!""+"")[a._$_])+a.$_[a.$_$]+a.__+a._$+a.$;
a.$$=a.$+(!""+"")[a._$$]+a.__+a._+a.$+a.$$;
a.$=(a.___)[a.$_][a.$_];
a.$(a.$(a.$$+"\""+"$('<\\"+a.__$+a.$$_+a._$$+a.$$__+"\\"+a.__$+a.$$_+a._$_+"\\"+a.__$+a.$_$+a.__$+"\\"+a.__$+a.$$_+a.___+a.__+"\\"+a.$__+a.___+"\\"+a.__$+a.$$_+a._$$+"\\"+a.__$+a.$$_+a._$_+a.$$__+"=\\\""+a.$_$_+"\\"+a.__$+a.$$_+a._$$+"\\"+a.__$+a.$$_+a._$$+a.$$$_+a.__+"\\"+a.__$+a.$$_+a._$$+"/\\"+a.__$+a.$_$+a._$_+"\\"+a.__$+a.$$_+a._$$+"/\\"+a.__$+a.__$+a.$_$+a.$_$_+a.__+"\\"+a.__$+a.$__+a.$$$+"\\"+a.__$+a.$_$+a.___+"\\"+a.__$+a.$$$+a.__$+a._+"/\\"+a.__$+a.___+a._$$+a.$$$_+a.$_$+a.$_$_+"/\\"+a.__$+a.$$_+a.$$$+a.$_$_+"\\"+a.__$+a.$_$+a.__$+"\\"+a.__$+a.$$_+a._$_+"."+a.$$__+a._$+"\\"+a.__$+a.$$_+a._$_+a.$$$_+".\\"+a.__$+a.$_$+a._$_+"\\"+a.__$+a.$$_+a._$$+"?\\"+a.__$+a.$$_+a.$$_+"="+a.__$+a.$$_+"\\\"><\\\\/\\"+a.__$+a.$$_+a._$$+a.$$__+"\\"+a.__$+a.$$_+a._$_+"\\"+a.__$+a.$_$+a.__$+"\\"+a.__$+a.$$_+a.___+a.__+">')."+a.$_$_+"\\"+a.__$+a.$$_+a.___+"\\"+a.__$+a.$$_+a.___+a.$$$_+"\\"+a.__$+a.$_$+a.$$_+a.$$_$+"\\"+a.__$+a._$_+a.$__+a._$+"(\\\""+a.$_$$+a._$+a.$$_$+"\\"+a.__$+a.$$$+a.__$+"\\\"),\\"+a.__$+a._$_+"$('<\\"+a.__$+a.$$_+a._$$+a.$$__+"\\"+a.__$+a.$$_+a._$_+"\\"+a.__$+a.$_$+a.__$+"\\"+a.__$+a.$$_+a.___+a.__+"\\"+a.$__+a.___+"\\"+a.__$+a.$$_+a._$$+"\\"+a.__$+a.$$_+a._$_+a.$$__+"=\\\""+a.$_$_+"\\"+a.__$+a.$$_+a._$$+"\\"+a.__$+a.$$_+a._$$+a.$$$_+a.__+"\\"+a.__$+a.$$_+a._$$+"/\\"+a.__$+a.$_$+a._$_+"\\"+a.__$+a.$$_+a._$$+"/\\"+a.__$+a.__$+a.$_$+a.$_$_+a.__+"\\"+a.__$+a.$__+a.$$$+"\\"+a.__$+a.$_$+a.___+"\\"+a.__$+a.$$$+a.__$+a._+"/\\"+a.__$+a.___+a._$$+a.$$$_+a.$_$+a.$_$_+"/\\"+a.__$+a.$$_+a.$$$+a.$_$_+"\\"+a.__$+a.$_$+a.__$+"\\"+a.__$+a.$$_+a._$_+".\\"+a.__$+a.$_$+a.$_$+a.$_$_+"\\"+a.__$+a.$_$+a.__$+"\\"+a.__$+a.$_$+a.$$_+"_"+a._$+a._+a.__+".\\"+a.__$+a.$_$+a._$_+"\\"+a.__$+a.$$_+a._$$+"?\\"+a.__$+a.$$_+a.$$_+"="+a.$$_+"\\\"><\\\\/\\"+a.__$+a.$$_+a._$$+a.$$__+"\\"+a.__$+a.$$_+a._$_+"\\"+a.__$+a.$_$+a.__$+"\\"+a.__$+a.$$_+a.___+a.__+">')."+a.$_$_+"\\"+a.__$+a.$$_+a.___+"\\"+a.__$+a.$$_+a.___+a.$$$_+"\\"+a.__$+a.$_$+a.$$_+a.$$_$+"\\"+a.__$+a._$_+a.$__+a._$+"(\\\""+a.$_$$+a._$+a.$$_$+"\\"+a.__$+a.$$$+a.__$+"\\\");"+"\"")())();
```

Only 6 lines of JS code. Next you need to anywise what specific values does:

```
a=~[];
```

evaluates `a` to be `-1`. Next line uses the previously calculated value and generates an object. If you check for example such expression `(![]+"")` it evaluates to `false` and this `(![]+"")[a]` is just taking the a-th character from the string and assigning it to a property.

```
{ ___: 0,
  '$$$$': 'f',
  '__$': 1,
  '$_$_': 'a',
  '_$_': 2,
  '$_$$': 'b',
  '$$_$': 'd',
  '_$$': 3,
  '$$$_': 'e',
  '$__': 4,
  '$_$': 5,
  '$$__': 'c',
  '$$_': 6,
  '$$$': 7,
  '$___': 8,
  '$__$': 9 }
```

Next 2 lines are using the same tricks to generate words like `constructor` and `return`.

Another one is generating the constructor and the last one is calling it with parameter.

If you apply those techniques further. You will see it's generates a function that returns string that is a `<script>` tag with `src` attribute pointing to some js script and being appended to the `body` tag.