# How can I deobfuscate this javascript code

Tags: deobfuscation, javascript

I am trying to deobfuscate this javascript code, but I don't know how it was created. Can you please tell me what the mechanism or the function is that generate such characters in javascript?

```
É=-~-~[],ó=-~É,Ë=É<<É,þ=Ë+~[];Ì=(ó-ó)[Û=(''+{})[É+ó]+(''+{})[ó-É]+([].ó+'')[ó-É]+(!!''+'')[ó]+({}+'')[ó+ó]+(!''+'')[ó-É]+(!''+'')[É]+(''+{})[É+ó]+({}+'')[ó+ó]+(''+{})[ó-É]+(!''+'')[ó-É]][Û];Ì(Ì((!''+'')[ó-É]+(!''+'')[ó]+(!''+'')[ó-ó]+(!''+'')[É]+((!''+''))[ó-É]+([].$+'')[ó-É]+'\''+''+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(þ)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(þ)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(É+É)+(þ)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó-ó)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(ó+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(þ)+(É)+'\\'+(É+É)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(É+É)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(þ)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(É+É)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(É+É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(É+É)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(É+É)+(þ)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(þ)+(ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(ó+ó)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(þ)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(þ)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(É+É)+(þ)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(þ)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(þ)+'\\'+(ó+ó)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(ó+ó)+(É)+'\\'+(ó+ó)+(ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(þ)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(É+É)+(þ)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(þ)+(ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(É+É)+(þ)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(ó+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(þ)+'\\'+(É+É)+(þ)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(þ)+(ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(þ)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(þ)+(ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(É+É)+(þ)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(ó+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó+ó)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó+ó)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó+ó)+'\\'+(É+É)+(þ)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(þ)+(ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(þ)+(É+ó)+'\'')())()
```

Comment: it's similar to this, already answered question: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/15943/18014

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The special "accent" letters are just a distraction. You can use a text-editor to replace them with "standard" letters and the code would still work.

Let's add a newline after each semicolon:

```
É=-~-~[],ó=-~É,Ë=É<<É,þ=Ë+~[];
Ì=(ó-ó)[Û=(''+{})[É+ó]+(''+{})[ó-É]+([].ó+'')[ó-É]+(!!''+'')[ó]+({}+'')[ó+ó]+(!''+'')[ó-É]+(!''+'')[É]+(''+{})[É+ó]+({}+'')[ó+ó]+(''+{})[ó-É]+(!''+'')[ó-É]][Û];
Ì(Ì((!''+'')[ó-É]+(!''+'')[ó]+(!''+'')[ó-ó]+(!''+'')[É]+((!''+''))[ó-É]+([].$+'')[ó-É]+'\''+''+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(þ)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(þ)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(É+É)+(þ)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó-ó)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(ó+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(þ)+(É)+'\\'+(É+É)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(É+É)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(þ)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(É+É)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(É+É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(É+É)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(É+É)+(þ)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(þ)+(ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(ó+ó)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(þ)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(þ)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(É+É)+(þ)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(þ)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(þ)+'\\'+(ó+ó)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(ó+ó)+(É)+'\\'+(ó+ó)+(ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(þ)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(É+É)+(þ)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(þ)+(ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(É+É)+(þ)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(ó+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(þ)+'\\'+(É+É)+(þ)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(þ)+(ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(þ)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(þ)+(ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(É+É)+(þ)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(ó+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó+ó)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó+ó)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó+ó)+'\\'+(É+É)+(þ)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(þ)+(ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(þ)+(É+ó)+'\'')())()
```

We can see that the first and second lines assign values to several variables (`É`, `ó`, `Ë`, `þ`, `Ì`). Then, the third line calls `Ì` (since it ends with '`()`').

In order to de-obfuscate the code, you can paste it in the browser console and replace the last two characters ('`()`') with `.toString()` - printing the function instead of calling it.

The result would be:

```
"function anonymous(
) {
a=prompt('Entrez le mot de passe');if(a=='toto123lol'){alert('bravo');}else{alert('fail...');}
}"
```